# failed in data insertion in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i've a table

```
 post(p_id,u_id(FK),date,title,type,viewer)
```

and a Modelclass UserModel.cs with(p_id,u_id,date,title,type).  When i  to create a new post in a post controller i tried like

```
 public ActionResult Create(PostModel p)
        {
```

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          p.date =  DateTime.Today;
          post post = new Models.DB.post();
          post.u_id = User.Identity.Name;
          post.date = p.date;
          post.title = p.title;
          post.type= p.type;
          post.viwer=1;

          try{      db.posts.AddObject(post);
                db.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("LoggedIndex");
         }
        catch{ return RedirectToAction("Index"); }
      }
    return View(p);
   }
```

It is not Working. I think from is not submitting when i submit always view is returned. i  i've created  stronly typed  create view. in create.cshtml i've two hidden field user_id and date of postModel Object. I'm very new at MVC.please help me thanks in advance....

Comment: do you want to save the data to a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sending Data from View to the Controler by using the MVC-Model**

I understand it like that: you have a mvc3 page and want to send some custom data to your controller:

**Controller:**

```
[http-post]
    public ActionResult Create(PostModel p)
        { 
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          p.date =  DateTime.Today;
          post post = new Models.DB.post();
          post.u_id = User.Identity.Name;
          post.date = p.date;
          post.title = p.title;
          post.type= p.type;
          post.viwer=1;

                db.posts.AddObject(post);
                db.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("LoggedIndex");
      }
    return View(p);
   }

public ActionResult Create()
        { 

    return View(new post());
   }
```

**View:**

```
@model post

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Controller-Name", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FORM" }))
{
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.date)

 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)

 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.title)

 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.type)
}
```

Further informations: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks Actually it was very silly mistake...<pre>public ActionResult Create()
        { 

    return View(new post());
   }
</pre> i did not</pre> return new post()</pre> i was wrote <pre>return View()</pre>